# FullCalendar custom header title

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I need to show a custom header title in the calendar. I am handling  16 calendars and I need every one of them to show their own title. I have tried everything I could modifying this part of the code:

```
firstDay: <?php echo $iFirstDay; ?>,
header: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
},
```

But everytime I edit the `center` to add something else apart from the `title` my calendar doesn't show any title at all. What should I do?

Comment: Will you please bother to add technology tag in your question?

Answer (score 31):

If you are using **fullCalender v2** you will have to escape string by putting them between scare brackets. This is because of the moment.js library ([see the moment doc](http://momentjs.com/docs/)).

So that would be

```
firstDay: <?php echo $iFirstDay; ?>,
header: {
  left: 'prev,next today',
  center: 'title',
  right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
},
titleFormat: '[Hello, World!]',
```

From moment.js doc:

> Escaping characters To escape characters in format strings, you can
> wrap the characters in square brackets.
>
> moment().format('[today] dddd'); // 'today Sunday'

Answer (score 9):

You don't change the `center` attribute. That just specifies what gets placed in the center of the header.

If you want to change the contents of the title itself, you need to change the [titleFormat](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/text/titleFormat/).

```
firstDay: <?php echo $iFirstDay; ?>,
header: {
  left: 'prev,next today',
  center: 'title',
  right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
},
titleFormat: '\'Hello, World!\'',
```

`titleFormat` uses a formatted date as the value, so if you want to display literal text, you need to wrap it in single quotes, but just remember to escape them.

Comment: I have a select on top of the calendar, so the events will change when selecting a different option. I do this with $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource',urlEvents); Is there a way to change the title dynamically?

Answer (score 1):

in fullCalender v6:

```
const calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
  titleFormat: (info) => `Year: ${info.date.year}  Month: ${info.date.month+1}`,
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. I use this to hack Buddhist era display:

```js
const computeTitle = FullCalendar.View.prototype.computeTitle;
FullCalendar.View.prototype.computeTitle = function (dateProfile) {
  const $ = jQuery;
  if (dateProfile.currentRangeUnit === 'month') {
      const cal = jQuery(".js-drupal-fullcalendar").fullCalendar('getCalendar');
      const era = cal.moment(dateProfile.date).year() + 543;
      return cal.moment(dateProfile.date).format('MMMM') + ' ' + era;
  }

  return computeTitle(dateProfile);
};
```

P.S: This pull request is seem to stale: https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/pull/3532

Answer (score -1):

you can just poke the name in before the calendar gets rendered, or even at the very top of the page:

```
<?php
echo "<center><h1>$fullname</h1></center>";
?>
```

Ugly, but works.